# Mark text (address etc.) and add to GMail contacts.

Tags: linux, chrome, gmail

Is there a program that lets me mark text in a browser or elsewhere and then turns that data into contact info and preferably directly adds it to GMail or a local address book?

I'm running Linux. I know of the evercontact extension in Chrome which I have tried but I don't feel comfortable letting an extension have access to everything in GMail.